# Serving protected files with Django and Nginx X-accel-redirect

Tags: django, nginx, x-accel-redirect

I'm trying to get Nginx and Django to play together to serve downloadable protected files. I just cannot get it to work. Here's my Nginx config:

```
location ~ ^.*/protected-test/ {
alias /<path-to-my-protected-files-on-server>/;
internal;
}
```

the relevant urls.py for viewing the file(s):

```
url(r'^static_files/downloads/protected-test/(?P<filename>.+)$', 'download_or_view',
{'download_dir': '%s%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'downloads/protected-test/'),
'content_disposition_type': 'inline',
'protected': 'True'},
name='protected_files')
```

my view:

```
def download_or_view(request, content_disposition_type, download_dir, filename=None, protected=False):

'''Allow a file to be downloaded or viewed,based on the request type and
     content disposition value.'''

if request.method == 'POST':
    full_path = '%s%s' % (download_dir, request.POST['filename'])
    short_filename = str(request.POST['filename'])
else:
    full_path = '%s%s' % (download_dir, filename)
    short_filename = str(filename)

serverfile = open(full_path, 'rb')
contenttype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(short_filename)
response = HttpResponse(serverfile, mimetype=contenttype)

if protected:
    url = _convert_file_to_url(full_path)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url.encode('utf-8')

response['Content-Disposition'] = '%s; filename="%s"' % (content_disposition_type, smart_str(short_filename))
response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(full_path).st_size

return response
```

I have 2 values in my settings file:

```
NGINX_ROOT = (os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'downloads/protected-test'))
NGINX_URL = '/protected-test'
```

_convert_file_to_url() takes the full file path and, using the two settings values above, turns it into a url that (I thought) Nginx would allow:

```
<domain-name>/protected-test/<filename>
```

So, if I try to access:

```
<domain-name>/static_files/downloads/protected-test/<filename>
```

In my browser window, it doesn't allow it (404). Good.

BUT - if I try to access that url from a form download, which I want to allow, I get a redirect in the browser to:

```
<domain-name>/protected-test/<filename>
```

and it's a 404 as well.

I've tried so many different configurations my brain now hurts. :-)

Should I not be reading the file with open(), and let Nginx serve it? If I remove that line, it returns a file with the dreaded zero bytes. Why do I still get a 404 on the redirected url??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I not be reading the file with open(),

That's correct. Your script shouldn't be opening the file. You just tell Nginx where the file exists and let it open the file and serve it.

I believe you want to just return an empty response after setting the appropriate headers

```
return HttpResponse('', mimetype=contenttype)
```

In PHP I setup the Nginx accel redirect by doing:

```
//Set content type and caching headers
//...
header("X-Accel-Redirect: ".$filenameToProxy);
exit(0);
```

i.e. exiting immediately after setting the header.

For the continuing 404 problem, you've probably got an error in the Nginx conf, but you need to post the rest to be sure. Your external URL appears to be something like:

```
static_files/downloads/protected-test/(?P<filename>.+)$
```

This will be matched on:

```
location ~ ^.*/protected-test/ {
    alias /<path-to-my-protected-files-on-server>/;
    internal;
}
```

giving the 404.

There is no need (and it's quite confusing) to have the same word `protected-test` in both the external URL and internal URL. I'd recommend not doing that i.e. have the external URL be like:

```
/static_files/downloads/(?P<filename>.+)$
```

Then have the internal location block be:

```
location ~ ^/protected-test {
    alias /<path-to-my-protected-files-on-server>;
    internal;
}
```

And then when you setup the x-accel-redirect header, swap between the two:

```
external_path = "/static_files/downloads";
nginx_path = "/protected-test";
filenameToProxy = str_replace(external_path, nginx_path, full_path);
header("X-Accel-Redirect: ".$filenameToProxy);
```

Rather than having the word `protected-test` be on both sides of the request.

Comment: K, thanks, that's one thing fixed - but still no luck on serving the file after the change.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the nginx conf?

Comment: A third party configured the nginx conf for me, I'll post it up asap. They say it's a default conf in emperor mode, plus the internal statement above.

Comment: Good idea on not naming both /protected-test, I'll try that. I also noticed you've got your internal conf as '~/protected-test' with no ending slash. Will that make a difference from my conf, which does have the ending slash?

Comment: It shouldn't - so long as you're consistent the ending being there or not. Nginx attaches anything after the matching text for the location block to the alias. So /protected-test/anything would be mapped to /<path-to-my-protected-files-on-server>/anything . I think the only issue could be where you have the slash in the location block but leave it off the alias path - which would not resolve to a real file.

Comment: Many thanks, got it working with your answer. Marked as correct.