# X-Accel-Redirect Nginx configuration not working

Tags: django, nginx, centos, web-deployment, nginx-config

I'm now deploying django projects on CentOS and have a problem with X-Accel-Redirect for protected file serving.

Here is my nginx.conf

```
server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name example;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /www/server/example;
        charset UTF-8;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/myproject_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myproject_error.log;
        client_max_body_size 75M;

        location /public/ {
          root /www/wwwroot/myproject/;
        }
        location /media/ {
          root /www/wwwroot/myproject/;
          internal;
        }
        location / {
          include uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass django;
        }
 ...
}
```

Of course, protected files are on `/www/wwwroot/myproject/media`.

And corresponding python view file is following.

```py
class ProtectedView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, id, target):        
        file_name = "1.png"
        response = HttpResponse()
        response["X-Accel-Redirect"] = "/media/{0}".format(file_name)
        response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={0}".format(file_name)

        return response
```

But server returns 404 error.

And the myproject_error.log is like this.

```
[error] 24570#0: *5 open() "/www/server/example/media/1.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 174.11.13.81, server: example, request: "GET /protected-view/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://0.0.0.0:8008", host: "40.1.12.23"
```

Maybe `location /media/ {}` block is not working. What problem? I have changed the permission but not working.
PS: I'm using django rest framework.

Comment: Can you put `index.html` in `/www/wwwroot/myproject/` and see if that works? :)

Comment: Of course. It works when get rid of `internal`. But I use `internal` restriction, and call it in python view. But not working.

Comment: Do you have any other `location` blocks, for example, to match URIs ending with `.png`?

Comment: No, other blocks are default configuration. But I have found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113602/serving-protected-files-with-django-and-nginx-x-accel-redirect/16114300#16114300).  I prepended "^~" to `location`. i.e. `location ^~ /media/ { }`